# load selected .txt file from datagridview and open the file in listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

so basically i have a data grid view that goes into a file and loads all of the .txt file names into a data grid view. What i need to do is when i click on a certain file in data grid view, it will open up the contents of that file into a list view.

Can anyone help as i am stuck?

I am guessing its something like:

if data grid view value = .txt file in the folder then load contents into listview.

sounds easy enough just unsure how to code this.

Thank you

I have this so far but still does not work:

```
private void gridProfiles_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (gridProfiles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
    {
        var path = gridProfiles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        path = Path.Combine(rootDirectory + "\\Profiles\\", path);

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {

                lstProcesses.Items.Add(path);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When i run this it gets ti if(file.exists(path) and then skips over it

route directory:

```
private static string rootDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\My File";


static void CreateDirectory()
    {
        string rootDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\My File";

        if (!Directory.Exists(rootDirectory)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(rootDirectory); }
        if (!Directory.Exists(rootDirectory + "\\Profiles")) { Directory.CreateDirectory(rootDirectory + "\\Profiles"); }
```

Comment: debug through, and check what you actually get for the `path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you create incorrect path, or you are reading incorrect cell value. Use overloaded `Path.Combine` which accept list of path parts. Also instead of adding `path` to list you should add `line`.

Following code will show you error message if file not exist with path where it tries to look for file. Also it will show error message if there is no file name in grid cell.

```
private void gridProfiles_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    object value = gridProfiles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

    if (value == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot get file name from grid");
        return;
    }

    var file = value.ToString();
    var path = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "Profiles", file); // create path

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(path + " not found");
        return;
    }

    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path))
        lstProcesses.Items.Add(line); // add line instead of path
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, was going to try yyour code but its erroring on the word "line" in the foreach loop, does not exist in current context

Comment: @Andrew I forgot to specify type, use `string` or `var`

Comment: added, var line; to specify then "in" gets highlighted which chucks error "type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement

Comment: think i got it, but when i run the code it went to the "if file does not exist" and shows the path is not found

Comment: @Andrew now you can see which path was generated and decide whether generation is wrong, or file is not exist

Comment: the file does exist. the datagridview loads all the file names in the folder. So when one of the cells is selected in the data grid view it follows the path exactly to where it got it from, but it still says it does not exist. I am really confused

Comment: @Andrew you are navigating to `rootDirectory/Profiles/filename.txt`. What is rootDirectory? Are you sure you need Profiles folder?

Comment: @Andrew from what path you read file names, and what is exact error message you see?

Comment: @lazyberezovosky No error but it reads when i run the program:

"c:\Users\Andrew ******\AppData\Roaming\My File\Profiles\ (file name) not found"

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand you - what means no error, if you show me error?

Comment: @lazyberezovosky the route directory code should be at top. Yes all errors have cleared. But when i run your code. it runs into the 'if (!File.Exists(path))' and says the path cannot be found

Comment: @Andrew if it says that file cannot be found, then it shows WHICH path cannot be found. Analyze that value

Comment: @lazyberezovosky this is what is confusing me because the path it shows me is the correct path to get to the file. I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: @Andrew set a breakpoint on line `if (!File.Exists(path))` and verify following things: **path**, **file**, and **rootDirectory**. If you will not find error by yourself, then post those three values here

Comment: file "Need For Speed" path: C:\\Users\\Andrew Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\My File\\Profiles\\Need For Speed

Comment: @Andrew and rootDirectory? Btw I don't see extension of file here.

Comment: It does not have the rootDirectory value, its identified by "path" the only values that come up are value, file and path

Comment: @Andrew move your cursor over `Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "Profiles", file)` line and see value of root

Comment: C:\\Users\\Andrew Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\My File .. Sorry, i am fairly new to programming, been programming for a few months

Comment: @Andrew I think your file should have extension `txt`. Try to change code `var file = value.ToString() + ".txt";`

Comment: works perfectly now! Damn, such a small little mistake! Thank you for your help, marking correct